# Problems with numpy arrays in plt.imshow()

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline
```

The following code shows the picture is black，Why not show white color?

```
a = np.ones(shape=(2, 2)) * 255
plt.imshow(a, cmap="gray")
```

Comment: try with another cmap, typically, if you use `plt.imshow(a, cmap="Greys_r")` it'll display a white image.

Answer (score 1):

plt.imshow() always normalizes by setting the minimum pixel to 0, and sclaing others between 0 and 1. If you have 1 pixel as 0, you could see what I mean.
If you wan't to avoid that, try:

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

Comment: What do you mean is that if the elements of my input array are the same, then the image will always be black by regularization, right?